# How to use Swift Package Manager's binaryTarget?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to use Swift Package Manager's binaryTarget to include the Stripe xcframework available here https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/releases/tag/v19.3.0.  The package manager doesn't complain, and lets me link to it, but I can't import it im.  I've made a sample repo to show it here https://github.com/martyu/StripePackageTest.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your example is not testable because you have forgotten to provide a version tag, so this is not a real package.

Second, and more important, I think you have a misconception about how a package works as a binary target. You seem to think that your Swift Package can contain code that sees the XCFramework. (That's why you are trying to `import` in the framework module in the Sources code of the package.) That's wrong. It's the *app* that imports the framework module. The package is merely a way of distributing the framework.

In other words, you can write a source code package or a framework-bearing package. One package cannot be both.

But of course you can write a source code package that *depends* on a framework-bearing package.

Comment: I don't want to use a framework at all, but the Stripe repo doesn't have SPM support.  So I thought I was stuck using their released .xcframework?  I didn't tag it because I expected people to download and try to build it, not import it from another app *shrug*. But it won't build with the import statement there.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about what `binaryTarget` is.  I equated depending on a binaryTarget to dragging a framework into an xcodeproj for an app.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing.  I moved all the code that depended on the Stripe framework into the main app project, and dragged the Stripe.xcframework into that.

Comment: All of this is in the video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10147/

Comment: So if I wrap the framework in its own package, I can import it like I would any other swift package.  So I could do that.  What I was originally trying to do was create a package that was dependent on the xcframework.  My example in that repo didn't show what I was trying to do properly.  I've updated it to show what I mean.

Comment: "What I was originally trying to do was create a package" As I said in my answer, what you've posted on GitHub is _not_ a package because you still have not added the version tag. As soon as you do, it will spring to life and will be available as a dependency, either for use by a project or by for use by another package.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't push my branch.  Now it's updated and has tags.  But it won't build the "Example" target because I can't import Stripe.

Comment: @matt I'm confused with this answer, and the conflicting note seen near the top of the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/distributing_binary_frameworks_as_swift_packages


"A Swift package can contain a mix of both source files and binaries. This use case is common for packages that contain source code that wraps closed-source binaries."

Comment: What did you mean by ~"provide a version tag"?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky provide = "create and push". version = "version string". tag = "tag" (Git)

Answer (score 1):

First, you *don't* need a version tag for it to be "real package". [You can specify package dependencies via commit SHA and branch as well](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#package-dependency-requirement). Also you can add local package repos in xcode via `file://`. Note, this is NOT the same as a local dev override.

I didn't have much luck with `swift build` but I did get it to work fine by creating an app in Xcode and adding the package to it. I think this is what @matt is getting at. You need to import it into a project (xcode, or another SP) and then xcode will assemble all the dependencies when it ~~builds~~ feels like it.

Here's the modified Package.swift I used.  I changed the name to **Example** (as that's presumably the SDK you are building which depends on Stripe). You can include "Stripe" in the Example library's targets if you want it embedded in its framework. Otherwise the client app just needs to import it as well (via the tickboxes when you add it in Xcode, or via `dependencies` in another `Package.swift`).

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Example",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
          name: "Example",
          type: .dynamic,
          targets: ["Example"]),
        .library(
            name: "Stripe",
            targets: ["Stripe"])
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        // I thought this was defining the Stripe binaryTarget...
        .binaryTarget(name: "Stripe",
                      url: "https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/releases/download/v19.3.0/Stripe.xcframework.zip",
                      checksum: "fe459dd443beee5140018388fd6933e09b8787d5b473ec9c2234d75ff0d968bd"),
        // ... and then linking it to the Example project here via "dependencies" ...
        .target(name: "Example", dependencies: ["Stripe"], path: "Sources")
        // ... so when I'm in "Example" files, I thought I'd be able to import "Stripe" to them
    ]
)
```

Comment: How to configure a binaryTarget which is xcframework zip file but in a private repo. I tried SSH but can you give an example of how the Package.swift would look like ?

Comment: @Max my guess would be that you'd either have an https or a git protocol'ed url just as for a public repo. You would just have to make sure the person using your SPM had access to the private repo when they added your swift package.